# LINQ Queries And Context

Tags: c#, linq

I have a slight issue with some code I'm writing

```
if(parameter == 1)
{
 var linq = from a in db.table select a;
}
else
{
 var linq  = from a in db.table where a.id = 1 select a;
}

foreach(var b in linq)
{
...
}
```

So basically what's going on is that the variable "linq" is different depending on the value of "parameter".  When I try to loop through "linq" with my foreach loop, I get an error about how linq doesn't exist in the current context.

What is the best way to work around this type of issue?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

What you tried doesn't work because the variable `linq` is already out of scope when you try to use it. You need to move the declaration to the outer scope.

To answer your question in a general way first: if you need to declare a variable before you assign to it, you can't use `var`. You need to declare the type explicitly:

```
IQueryable<Something> linq;
if(parameter == 1)
{
    linq = from a in db.table select a;
}
else
{
    linq = from a in db.table where a.id == 1 select a;
}
```

In your particular example though you can simplify things:

```
var query = from a in db.table select a;
if (parameter != 1)
{
    query = query.Where(a => a.id == 1);
}
```

Comment: +1 but based on the OP's sample I think it should be `if (parameter != 1)` (for the 2nd code sample)

Comment: Oh right, you can query linq results (which is such a fundamentally important feature of linq that I'm just starting to appreciate).  This is very helpful, thanks!

Comment: @Soo: I'm querying the *query*, which gives a new *query*. There are no results until you ask for them, for example by writing `foreach (var result in query)`.

Comment: @Mark, Thank you for that correction, It's valuable for me to pick up the correct terminology as I pick these concepts up.  :)

Comment: @SLaks: Are you sure? `db.table` probably has type `Table<Something>` which I think would cause the assignment further down to fail with a type error (`cannot convert from IQueryable<T> to Table<T>`).

Answer (score 0):

I dunno if this is the best way but, assuming you're returning the same table.

```
var linq  = from a in db.table where a.id = 1 select a;

if(parameter == 1)
{
 linq = from a in db.table select a;
}

//foreach.
```

You can reconstruct your linq query and not pay a big penalty, since you haven't actually executed it.